# How to used scope slot to class bindings in Laravel Vue Setup

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a `Laravel` and `Vue` setup in my development, I'm trying to use the `v-slot="{ errors }"` in my class bindings.

Here's the code.

```
<validation-provider name="Name" rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">

<tr :class="[errors.length ? 'border-red-500 border' : 'border' ]">
```

and this error appears

`Property or method "errors" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.`

Comment: do you pass it from your a `blade` file?

Comment: @Joseph No. The `errors` is coming from `validation-provider` a javascript component

Comment: I mean the `validation-provider` component did you call it from a blade file?

Comment: Yes from the blade file

Comment: so all you need is to pass the `errors` object with mustache syntax like this `{{ errors() }}`

Comment: something else i forgot it is a function needs to be called like this `{{ errors() }}`

Comment: can you put the actual code? because based on the code that you sent here, it will look for a method `errors()` in php not in a vue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233081/discussion-between-joseph-and-nethkennnnn).